# Android TreeView lib and proguard encounter

Tags: android, proguard

There is really nice lib for creating tree view in android, [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).

This library works fine until I  enabled the `proguard`, then the app getting crashed.

**Note**: i have a `ViewPager` with 5 fragments that all of them using `treeview`.

With default progaurd setting i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate class class com.mehdok.c.c
            at com.mehdok.e.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.e.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.e.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.e.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.e.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.b.b.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.mehdok.b.b.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

So i tried to change proguard setting:

```
-keep public class com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView
-keep public class com.mehdok.views.treeview.SimpleViewHolder
-keep public class com.mehdok.views.treeview.TreeNode
-keep public interface com.mehdok.views.treeview.TreeNode$TreeNodeClickListener
-keep public class com.mehdok.views.treeview.TreeNode$BaseNodeViewHolder
-keep public class com.mehdok.views.treeview.TreeNodeWrapperView
-keep class com.mehdok.views.treeview.** { *; }
-keep public class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder
-keep public class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder$TreeViewItem
```

Now i'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate class class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder
        at com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView.getViewHolderForNode(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView.addNode(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView.expandNode(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView.getView(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.views.treeview.AndroidTreeView.getView(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.b.b.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.mehdok.b.b.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
```

A related part of proguard `mapping` text:

```
com.mehdok.fragments.Tab1Fragment -> com.mehdok.b.b:
    com.mehdok.fragments.Tab1Fragment mInstance -> a
    android.widget.FrameLayout baseView -> b
    com.mehdok.fragments.Tab1Fragment getInstance() -> a
    android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,android.view.ViewGroup,android.os.Bundle) -> onCreateView
    void findViews(android.view.View) -> a
    void fillView() -> b
```

TreeViewHolder.java

```
public class TreeViewHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<TreeViewHolder.TreeViewItem>
{
    public TreeViewHolder(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, TreeViewItem value)
    {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.treeview_layout, null, false);
        TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_text);
        tvValue.setText(value.nodeName);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle(boolean active)
    {
        super.toggle(active);
    }

    public static class TreeViewItem
    {
        public String nodeName;
        public int nodeNavNum;
        public int nodeDeep;

        public TreeViewItem(String name, int nav, int deep)
        {
            nodeName = name;
            nodeNavNum = nav;
            nodeDeep = deep;
        }
    }
}
```

Tab1Fragment.java

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment
{
    private static Tab1Fragment mInstance;
    private FrameLayout baseView;

    public static Tab1Fragment getInstance()
    {
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new Tab1Fragment();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    public Tab1Fragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        findViews(v);
        fillView();

        return v;
    }

    private void findViews(View v)
    {
        baseView = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.tab1_base_layout);
    }

    private void fillView()
    {
        TreeNode root = TreeCreator.createTitle1Tree();
        AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), root);
        tView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
        tView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyle);
        tView.setDefaultViewHolder(TreeViewHolder.class);
        //tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(nodeClickListener);

        baseView.addView(tView.getView());
    }   

}
```

So how can i config progaurd to work for me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keeping the view holder solved the problem

```
-keep public class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder
-keep public class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder$TreeViewItem
-keepclassmembers class com.mehdok.holders.TreeViewHolder {
    public *;
    private *;
}
```

Comment: I have been struggling to solve this exact problem for a week now. You sir saved the day.